# Swift - converting video to data and String returns nil with UTF8 encoding - sending video via HTTP POST to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video

High level explanation of the problem (in Swift 5)

1. I'm recording a video in MOV using `AVAssetWriter`
2. I'm encoding the video in MP4 using `exportSession.exportAsynchronously` (however I can skip this step and I still have the same problem)
3. I send the video via HTTP POST to a AWS S3 bucket with:

   `let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:videoPathMP4.path, options:[]) as Data`

   `let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)`

`fileContent` is now `nil` meaning the video data cannot be interpreted in UTF8. If I use UTF16 it works (I get a string back) but when I receive the message on the server side it's not a readable MP4 file (it's corrupted?). I have the feeling it's because it should be a string in UTF8 but I cannot turn the video data to UTF8 string to send to the server.

How can I send this data in UTF8 or how can I just send the video data in NSData format? Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Here are my code snippets from the different steps:

Step 1 - recording video in MOV:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer).seconds
            switch _captureState {
            case .start:
                print ("starting to record")
                // Set up recorder
                _filename = UUID().uuidString
                let videoPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(_filename).mov")
                let writer = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoPath, fileType: .mov)
                let settings = _videoOutput!.recommendedVideoSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov)
                let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: settings) 
                input.mediaTimeScale = CMTimeScale(bitPattern: 600)
                input.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
                input.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
                let adapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: input, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)
                if writer.canAdd(input) {
                    writer.add(input)
                }
                writer.startWriting()
                writer.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
                _assetWriter = writer
                _assetWriterInput = input
                _adpater = adapter
                _captureState = .capturing
                _time = timestamp
            case .capturing:
                if _assetWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
                    let time = CMTime(seconds: timestamp - _time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600))
                    _adpater?.append(CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!, withPresentationTime: time)
                }
                break
            case .end:
                guard _assetWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true, _assetWriter!.status != .failed else { break }
                _assetWriterInput?.markAsFinished()
                _assetWriter?.finishWriting { [weak self] in
                    self?._captureState = .idle
                    self?._assetWriter = nil
                    self?._assetWriterInput = nil
                    print ("Finished writing video file: \(self!._filename)")
                }
            default:
                break
            }

}
```

Step 2 - encoding the video in MP4 (made synchronous to avoid race conditions with sending data):

```
    func encodeVideo(at videoURL: URL, completionHandler: ((URL?, Error?) -> Void)?)  {
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)

    let startDate = Date()

    //Create Export session
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
        completionHandler?(nil, nil)
        return
    }

    //Creating temp path to save the converted video
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")

    //Check if the file already exists then remove the previous file
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
        } catch {
            completionHandler?(nil, error)
        }
    }

    exportSession.outputURL = filePath
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
      let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)
    let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: avAsset.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = range

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        switch exportSession.status {
        case .failed:
            print(exportSession.error ?? "NO ERROR")
            completionHandler?(nil, exportSession.error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export canceled")
            completionHandler?(nil, nil)
        case .completed:
            //Video conversion finished
            let endDate = Date()

            let time = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            print(time)
            print("Successful!")
            print(exportSession.outputURL ?? "NO OUTPUT URL")
            completionHandler?(exportSession.outputURL, nil)

            default: break
        }
        group.leave()
    })
    group.wait(timeout: .now() + 10.0) // blocks current queue
}
```

Step 3 - Send Video (obtain a temporary URL to S3 and auth to send the actual video file, then sending the video file - all calls made blocking calls):

```
    private func sendVideo(filename: String, recordID: String){
    
    //Obtain temporary URL and credentials
    let url = URL(string: "https://<OMITTED>")!

    //JSON Payload for server
    let data = [
                "recordid" : recordID,
    ] as [String : Any]
    
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    Helper.sendVideoURLRequestToRestAPI(url: url, data: data)
        { response, json, error in
                // will be called at either completion or at an error.
        
                guard let statusCode = response?.statusCode else{
                    print ("[sendVideo] no status code returned - request failed")
                    return
                }
                print ("Status Code from server: \(statusCode)")
        
                if statusCode != 200 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error submitting data - please try again! - \(json["body"] as? String)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert2, animated: true)
                    }

                } else { //success
                    
                    let videoURL = json["url"] as! String

                    let parameters = [
                      [
                        "key": "key",
                        "value": (json["fields"] as! [String : Any])["key"]!,
                        "type": "text"
                      ],
                      [
                        "key": "AWSAccessKeyId",
                        "value": (json["fields"] as! [String : Any])["AWSAccessKeyId"]!,
                        "type": "text"
                      ],
                      [
                        "key": "signature",
                        "value": (json["fields"] as! [String : Any])["signature"]!,
                        "type": "text"
                      ],
                      [
                        "key": "policy",
                        "value": (json["fields"] as! [String : Any])["policy"]!,
                        "type": "text"
                      ],
                      [
                        "key": "x-amz-security-token",
                        "value": (json["fields"] as! [String : Any])["x-amz-security-token"]!,
                        "type": "text"
                      ],
                      [
                        "key": "file",
                        "src": filename, 
                        "type": "file",
                        "contentType": "video/mp4"
                      ]
                    ] as [[String : Any]]

                    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
                    var body = ""
                    var error: Error? = nil
                    for param in parameters {
                        if param["disabled"] == nil {
                            let paramName = param["key"]!
                            body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                            body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
                            if param["contentType"] != nil {
                              body += "\r\nContent-Type: \(param["contentType"] as! String)"
                            }
                            let paramType = param["type"] as! String
                            if paramType == "text" {
                              let paramValue = param["value"] as! String
                              body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)\r\n"
                            } else {
                                let paramSrc = param["src"] as! String
                                print("paramSrc: \(paramSrc)")
                                let videoPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(paramSrc).mov")
                                
                                self.encodeVideo(at: videoPath, completionHandler: { url, error in
                                    guard error == nil else {
                                        print ("error video mp4 conversion")
                                        print(String(describing: error))
                                        return
                                    }
                                })
                                let videoPathMP4 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")

                                do {
                                    let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile:videoPathMP4.path, options:[]) as Data
                                    let fileContent = String(data: fileData, encoding: .utf8)! //Exception thrown here - IF I change this to UTF16 it doesn't throw an exception but the file arrives corrupted on server side.

                                    body += "; filename=\"\(paramName)\"\r\n"
                                    + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n" //paramName = paramSrc
                                
                                  //  print ("Body: \(body)")
                                } catch {
                                    print ("Could not open video file: \(videoPathMP4.path)")
                                    return
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    body += "--\(boundary)--\r\n";
                    let postData = body.data(using: .utf8) //UTF8

                    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: videoURL)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
                    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.httpMethod = "POST"
                    request.httpBody = postData


                    let session = URLSession.shared
                    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                        guard error == nil else {
                            print ("error")
                            print(String(describing: error))
                            return
                        }

                        guard let data = data else {
                            print ("Error unpacking data")
                            print(String(describing: error))
                            //semaphore.signal()
                            return
                        }

                        print ("data \(data) - \(response)")
                        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    })
                    task.resume()

                    group.leave()
                }
        }
    group.wait() // blocks current queue
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the Data` to be opened as a `String`? If you need to convert `Data` to `String` you need to use `base64encoding`

Comment: I thought that's the way to put video data into the body of the POST message and send it. I assume that's wrong?

Comment: You can not convert any data to string

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61226588/2303865

Answer (score 0):

```
 let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
            var body = ""
            var error: Error? = nil
            for param in parameters {
              if param["disabled"] == nil {
                let paramName = param["key"]!
                body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(paramName)\""
                if param["contentType"] != nil {
                  body += "\r\nContent-Type: \(param["contentType"] as! String)"
                }
                let paramType = param["type"] as! String
                if paramType == "text" {
                  let paramValue = param["value"] as! String
                  body += "\r\n\r\n\(paramValue)\r\n"
                } else {
                  let paramSrc = param["src"] as! String
                    print("KMKM",paramSrc)
                    
                  let fileData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile:paramSrc)
                      print("mcmjdc",fileData)
                    
                    let fileContent = String(data: fileData! as Data, encoding: .utf8)!
                  body += "; filename=\"\(paramSrc)\"\r\n"
                    + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n"
                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).